# How can I use English international with AltGr as input source in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome, keyboard

How can I use English international with AltGr as input source in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Go to Settings → *Keyboard*.
2. In the *Input Sources* section click <kbd>+</kbd> → *English (United States)*, select *English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)* and click *Add* on the top right of the window.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @anayarojo I'm glad I was able to help you :)